# There's no "all" where I can pass a lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python doesn't have a method "all" where I can pass a lambda? Or have I missed anything? I'm aware about list comprehension, but how about this?

```
 res = map(....., [True, False, False, ......very long])
 # how to check that all items in "res" are True using a functional approach?
```

Yes, there're the ways to check that, but there's no functional way? I want to do something like:

```
res2 = all(lambda x: x == True, res)
```

Comment: Why do you need a callback when you're testing for the same thing `all` is already testing for? If that's not your actual example, a more realistic one would help.

Comment: If you comprehend comprehension, then why not, e.g., `all(x > 5 for x in res)`? It's not *functional*, but it works perfectly fine and with the same or better performance characteristics. – Python - *one* way to do things.

Comment: In fact, you can shorten your example, like this `all(map(...., [True, False....]))`

Comment: @deceze, because of my preferences.

Comment: Comparing the documentation for `all` and `map` (for example), no. `all` simply takes an iterable. So you have to use list/generator comprehension

Comment: Okay, Python doesn't support a function with `all`, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: What preferences? If `res` really is a `list` with `[True, False, False, ....]`, you can just do `all(res)` and be done. That's the point of `all()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, and if not?

Comment: Personally I *prefer* the simplest solution to a problem, which a generator expression clearly would be. IMO.

Comment: @deceze, I'm very happy for you. So what?

Comment: Well, again, the Python mantra is *one obvious way to do things*, which is a generator expression. So to answer your question: no, there's no `all` which accepts a lambda. *Because* there's already a perfectly fine alternative.

Comment: @deceze, re-read the question.

Comment: @AlanCoromano, you do realise we are here to _help_ you? A less pedantic tone will go great lengths to get good, informed answers from us.

Comment: `output = all(map(lambda x: x > 5, input))`

Comment: Re-read it. Still unclear why you insist on a functional solution, when the only issue is that your preferences are at odds with Python's philosophy.

Comment: @deceze, why? Because. My question is about whether or not a function "all" or alternative exists.

Comment: No, it doesn't. \* Without bending over backwards.

Comment: @deceze, that's it then.

Comment: I mean, I guess you could do `all((lambda x: x==True)(item) for item in res)`, but that could be shortened to `all((lambda x: x)(item) for item in res`, or, even faster and more readable, `all(res)`. Functional programming doesn't mean shoehorning functions where they don't belong.

Comment: If `res` isn't a `list` of boolean values, could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in function, but you can easily write it yourself by composing `map` with `all`:

```
def all_function(predicate, iterable):
    return all(map(predicate, iterable))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no `all` implementation which accepts a callback, because the same can be expressed using a generator expression. Using the more complex "check if all values are over 5" example for a better sample:

```
res = map(..)
if all(x > 5 for x in res):
    print('Yes!')
```

There's no specific *need* to provide an alternative implementation of `all` here, since this pattern can handle anything you want, and Python's mantra is to have *one obvious way to do things.*

Answer (score 0):

`all(function(x) for x in res)` is the proper way to use a function with `all()`, but if you insist on doing it the 'functional way', try [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x == True, res)) == res
```

Comment: Wow, this has ***much*** worse performance characteristics than `all`.

Comment: @deceze: sure, but it can be used with `lambda`s!

Comment: You could bend over backwards any number of ways to get to the same result, but only a very small handful of these ways are sane. This here isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `all` with a functionality like `lambda x: x == True`. It's a redundant job because `all()` that's exactly what this functions stands for, but if you want to check the validity of an iterable items adn then use `all()`, one pythoic way is using a generator expression within `all()` by calling the custom function on iterable items.

```
all(func(x) for x in res)
```

Note that the `func()` should returns a bool value for each item. Or at least a result which interpret as False by python.